# Video does not appear when I build the project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a website using ReactJS, and in the initial part I put a background video, when I open the ReactJs website on my computer the video appears normally without any problem, but when I build the project, the video stops appearing.

```
npm run build
serve -s build
```

Images:

The video is the apple logo in the background -

[image: screenshot]

Situation when I build.

[image: screenshot]

Code.

[image: screenshot]

Project source code: https://github.com/ThiagoCComelli/reactjs/blob/master/src/components/Main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your code.

You need to change the `src` of the video element.

Your code:

```
<video src="/videos/AppleStore.mp4" autoPlay muted loop className="myVideo" />
```

Change to:

```
<video src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/videos/AppleStore.mp4`} autoPlay muted loop className="myVideo" />
```